# How to open firewall port with ansible firewalld task on Centos 7

Tags: centos, firewall, ansible, firewalld

I have a task in my ansible-playbook script to open TCP port on a remote machine. but when I run my ansible playbook it throws an error. But when i run `"firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=1234/tcp"` and `"firewalld-cmd --reload"` I can see port is added in public zone.

Environment
Ansible local: OS x El Capitan
Ansible remote: AWS Centos 7 minimum version
Ansible version: 2.1.1.0
Remote python version: 2.7.5

My task

```
- name: open management console port
  firewalld: port=1234/tcp zone=public permanent=true state=enabled immediate=yes
```

The error I am getting

```
fatal: [X.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_MojhHQ/ansible_module_firewalld.py\", line 605, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_MojhHQ/ansible_module_firewalld.py\", line 456, in main\r\n    is_enabled = get_port_enabled_permanent(zone, [port, protocol])\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_MojhHQ/ansible_module_firewalld.py\", line 170, in get_port_enabled_permanent\r\n    fw_zone = fw.config().getZoneByName(zone)\r\n  File \"<string>\", line 2, in getZoneByName\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slip/dbus/polkit.py\", line 103, in _enable_proxy\r\n    return func(*p, **k)\r\n  File \"<string>\", line 2, in getZoneByName\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firewall/client.py\", line 52, in handle_exceptions\r\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firewall/client.py\", line 1505, in getZoneByName\r\n    path = dbus_to_python(self.fw_config.getZoneByName(name))\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py\", line 70, in __call__\r\n    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slip/dbus/proxies.py\", line 50, in __call__\r\n    return dbus.proxies._ProxyMethod.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py\", line 145, in __call__\r\n    **keywords)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py\", line 651, in call_blocking\r\n    message, timeout)\r\ndbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.fedoraproject.slip.dbus.service.PolKit.NotAuthorizedException.org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.config: \r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.fedoraproject.slip.dbus.service.PolKit.NotAuthorizedException.org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.config` indicates there's some sort of permissions error.  The task probably needs to elevate its privileges with `become: yes`.

See [the `become` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes that is the case. Thanks @XiongChiamiov

Answer (score 6):

```
- name: Install firewalld
      yum:
        name: firewalld
        state: latest
      notify:
        - start firewalld
    - name: start firewalld
      service:
        name: firewalld
        state: started
        enabled: yes
      become: yes
    - name: enable 1234
      firewalld:
        zone: public
        port: 1234/tcp
        permanent: true
        state: enabled
      become: yes
```

Do it this way . It will work